# JSON parsing of the login webservice for API23 and above

Tags: android, json, web-services

its not a good practice to downgrade your sdk,but on a API23 json parsing using HTTPCLIENT doesnt work.it says that its removed in API 23.What should i do to implement JSON paring for login webservice in android studio.if not how to change the API level in android studio.i tried to change in Gradle.build but couldnt solve the issue.Thanks in advance..

Comment: Json parsing?? how about using the regular JSONObject class

Comment: I recommend parsing with [Jackson library](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDataBinding). You can transform your plain old java objects (POJOs) with some annotations to JSON and vice versa.

Comment: You want to communicate with the server, but can't use HttpClient, right?

Comment: Please reframe your question according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

You should use HttpURLConnection library instead of HttpClient. Refer to the documentation : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html